# Can I replace data in PHP from my database like this?

Tags: php, sql

I have a database and there is a row named `user_role`. The default value is set to `0` by me using `PHP`.

If I want to replace that `0` with a string like `Member` or `Admin` can I write something like:

```
$result_from_db = 0;

if($result_from_db == 0) {
  $role = "Member";
} elseif($result_from_db == 1) {
  $role = "Admin";
} else {
  $role = "Invalid!";
}

echo $role;  // Changes the value from DB to my custom string
```

Although I can rename `0` to `Member` in the DB, I want to know if something like this is possible.

Comment: Sure that is possible. But it is hard to maintain, since you have to go through your code for every tiny modification of your database model. Instead take a look at a "object relational mapper" (ORM).

Comment: Yes its possible, your code proves it, sidenote if you use something like rbac http://phprbac.net the *role*'s are easier to change/add

Comment: You're not really replacing data, this doesn't modify the database, nor does it modify the result retrieved from the database.  You've just created a new variable $role and assigned a value based on the satisfied condition.

Comment: Didn't know about ORM or RBAC, will check it out now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible but not recommended way. Instead, use child table to store role names.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the `CASE`, See [SQL CASE](https://community.modeanalytics.com/sql/tutorial/sql-case/)

```
SELECT id, name, user_role
CASE
    WHEN user_role = 0 THEN "Member"
    WHEN user_role = 1 THEN "Admin"
    ELSE "Invalid!" 
END AS user_role_string
FROM user_table;
```

Comment: Thanks, will consider using this. Can this also be done from PHP? Is there any downside to it?

Comment: Yes, your existing php code should work. But I think you can get proper formatted data using `SQL CASE` without doing any further extra processing in PHP side

Comment: @HDG390x I don't see any downside of using the PHP version. You can got with that but SQL CASE seems cool to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can hard-code these associations using a `CASE` statement, but whether or not you should is a different question.

What you're describing is a foreign key relationship.  Where the identifier `0` has a label of `'Member'`, the identifier `1` has a label of `'Admin'`, etc.

If you hard code these associations to their labels, any changes need to be replicated in every piece of code where you've don the hard coding.  Instead, why not just have another table of roles?

```
CREATE TABLE user_role (
  id             INT,
  label          VARCHAR(32),
  is_admin       INT,
  is_super_user  INT,
  is_a_moomin    INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Then you just use a `JOIN` to look up the label or property you want...

```
SELECT
  user_table.*,
  user_role.label   AS user_role_label
FROM
  user_table
INNER JOIN
  user_role
    ON user_role.id = user_table.role_id
```

Additionally, by having this table you can create foreign key Constraints.

```
ALTER TABLE user_table ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_user_role (user_id) REFERENCES user_role (id)
```

Then the database can ensure that the value in `user_table.role_id` ***must*** exist in `user_role.id`.

These are all fundamental aspects of what Relational Databases are for and how they are intended to work.  Different databases have slightly different syntax for these. I strongly advise looking in to them and researching database standard practices for using these constructs.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL "relational way" to do that would be to have a table called `roles` and pull the data from that table using the `user_role` column as a foreign key to the `roles` table. The (very simplified) table definition would look something like this:

```
Table: roles
------------------
*id:     int(10)
name:    varchar(200)
```

where `id` is the primary key of that table. Then, to get a user with its role, you execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM users, roles WHERE users.user_role = roles.id AND (...any other conditions you have)
```

You can add more roles to your `roles` table and the SQL statement would still be the same.